# How to show ellipses to the overflew text for HTML elements in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css

I need to show the ellipses(...) if the text overflows in DIVs and SPANs.

I have a CSS attribute called `text-overflow:ellipses`. But this works only in IE.

I want to display the same in other browsers like Firefox/Chrome etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article (http://mattlaine.com/blog/?p=49)](http://mattlaine.com/blog/?p=49) explains how to do it for Firefox.

There is also [a jQuery plugin](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/) that will add the ellipses for Firefox.

`text-overflow: ellipsis` works on a few other browsers, like Safari.  Opera uses `-o-text-overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
text-overflow:  ellipsis | clip
```

Answer (score 0):

This property is not implemented in Firefox ..
They mention that you can use the `-moz-binding` to simulate this

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow