# Text wrap with fixed max-height

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I need to have a box (div) with some text over multiple lines, and this box needs to have a fixed width and a fixed max height.

I'm using the `overflow: hidden;` Now my problem is that if the last line doesn't fit in the div max height it will get cut (cutting just half of the line for example). What I want to do in this case is not to show the last line, and display ellipsis in the last one

My problem is not inserting ellipsis in a single text line (using the `white-space: nowrap` property), the main problem is that the text gets cutted in the last line, ellipsis is not an issue because in last case I can use jQuery to insert it

Comment: Try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067696/how-to-show-ellipses-to-the-overflew-text-for-html-elements-in-firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

to the Div

EDIT: ok, not possible for now, not in a standardized way.

BUT, it's possible to achieve it with experimental webkit features (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004006/is-vertical-text-overflow-possible-with-css3)),
or to do it with JS through [the solution](http://reusablebits.com/post/2642059628/introducing-clamp-js) written by this guy, and hosted on github.

Comment: I think those links will solve my problems, Thanks. I will try and give a feedback